# Can I predict the time & size of a computation given a small set of stats?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I encrypt a file, and the resulting (encrypted) file is of a certain `Size`.

I can increase the `Strength` of the encryption and the `Size` of the resulting file will also increase in that case.

The `Time` it takes to then decrypt the file also increases when the `Strength` of the encryption is increased.

I ran `8` tests in total increasing the `Strength` by `5` every time and here are the results:

| Strength | Time (to decrypt in secs) | Size of encrypted file (Mb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.013 | 0.000088 |
| 5 | 0.064 | 0.001024 |
| 10 | 0.139 | 0.005376 |
| 15 | 0.199 | 0.023744 |
| 20 | 0.305 | 0.101144 |
| 25 | 0.503 | 0.427328 |
| 30 | 1.086 | 1.80188 |
| 35 | 3.348 | 7.59422 |
| 40 | 14.191 | 32.003072 |

I'm trying to figure out a pattern here, i.e. the relation between the `Strength`, `Time` & `Size`.

My computer crashes for any `Strength > 40` so I was wondering if based on these stats alone there is a way to more or less predict the `Time` and `Size` for a `Strength = 1000` for example (or other).

EDIT: I am not a mathematician and I have no experience with *functions* coming up with *formulas* etc. :-)

Comment: Fit a linear function, or exponential, or polynomial (up to degree $n$ of your choosing).

Comment: Conman has given you a great answer about how to analyse your data. However, why don't you analyse the algorithms rather than experimental data? [Aside: I would be deeply suspicious of an encryption algorithm for which the size of the cipher-text grows significantly as the key-length grows,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to figure something out like this, your first thought should always be "get lots of data" and your second thought should be "plot the data". In this case you've got an acceptable number of data points, so for now let's skip right to the plots. I pasted your table into a Google Sheets spreadsheet and tried its default "Insert Chart" option and got this:

[image: Line chart of Time and Size against Strength, showing some kind of growth]

So yes, increasing strength does make the other variables increase in a way that's more than linear. The next step would be to change the vertical axis to a logarithmic one - i.e. where the gap between ticks represents multiplying by a consistent value rather than adding one (e.g. going 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100 instead of -2, -1, 0, 1, 2) and we see something that might be useful:

[image: The same chart with a logarithmic scale, showing that size is growing linearly on this scale]

Notice how, except at the far left, the red line is practically flat? That's a *very* good sign, because it means we can assume that the relationship between Size and Strength is exponential, i.e. $Size = k \times \alpha ^ {Strength}$ for some values of $k$ and $\alpha$. Now we could go through the mathematics of fitting the function, but for simplicity I just asked Google for an exponential trendline and it gave it to me:

[image: Adding the trendline to the Size plot with equation]

Here, the equation of the trendline is estimated as "3.2E-04e^0.288x", or in other words $Size = 0.00032 e^{-0.288 \times Strength} \approx 0.00032 \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{Strength}$ which means that increasing the Strength of the encryption by 1 increases the size of the file by 33%. It looks like the behaviour isn't exactly right at the bottom end, which might be a function of how the encryption works (it would be good to try encrypting several files of the same size to eliminate anything that's unique to your particular file, and also try encrypting files of different size to see how everything scales in that direction too).

Now, what about the Time? It's not quite as nice a line there, so I suspect that the relationship is not quite exponential - there might be multiple processes that are involved and one may be exponential while the other is polynomial, or something. The data is probably not enough to make any definitive rulings. If I do the same and add an exponential trendline, then I get the equation $Time = 0.00517 e^{0.195 \times Strength} \approx 0.00517 \left(1.215\right)^{Strength}$, so increasing Strength by 1 adds a factor of about 22% to the time to decrypt, but the fact that the trend doesn't fit as well means we expect that to break down faster than the size equation.

Comment: Wow, this is is very helpful! Thank you so much for this. Would it help if I run the tests and increased the Difficulty by 1 every time (so 40 tests in total instead of 8) ? Unfortunately I cannot go beyond 40. Btw, the original unencrypted file I started with was 0.000011Mb (11 bytes) - a simple String of 11 characters. And then I kept encrypting it over and over again (a Difficulty of 3 means the file was encrypted 3 times and so on...). I have to give your answer multiple reads though. :-)

Comment: Also, Time is indeed an issue as it depends on the processing power of the computer you happen to run your tests on at the time, the other background processes at the time etc.. So it is depends on other parameters as well but these results have a predictive value nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, it may help a little to fill in some of the gaps (and also to try the same strength on different files on the same length so that you have some independent data points). I agree that time is not necessarily going to be as predictable unless you have access to a "CPU time" measure that actually checks how long the CPU actively works on the process.